# WPF Collapsing nodes in a TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

So, I have a treeview in which I have a list. I want to apply a filter to it, and all nodes that doesn't meet the words on the filter are collapsed, so they don't take space.

The problem is, even if I set them as collapsed, they still take a minimum amount of space...

```
        <TreeView x:Name="UserTree">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
     Color="Transparent" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}"
     Color="Black" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
     Color="Transparent" />
            <local:SumConverter x:Key="sumConverter"/>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding UserList}">
                <Border x:Name="headerTree" Background="#FFD3D1D1" CornerRadius="3" Padding="2"
     Margin="2">
                    <Grid Width="330" Height="20">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Name="txtGroupName" Width="280"
     Height="20" FontFamily="Palatino Linotype" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center"
     AllowDrop="True" Drop="TextBlock_Drop" Padding="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
     Margin="0,2,0,0" />
                        <CheckBox x:Name="cbSelector" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
     VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" Checked="cbSelector_Checked"
     Unchecked="cbSelector_Unchecked" />
                    </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="320" Visibility="{Binding isVisible}">
                                <CheckBox Margin="16,1,1,1" VerticalAlignment="center"
     Checked="ChkUser_Checked" Unchecked="chkUser_Unchecked" 
                                    IsChecked="{Binding IsListed}"
     PreviewMouseMove="CheckBox_PreviewMouseMove" 
                                    PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="CheckBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" ToolTipService.ToolTip="
    {Binding Section}">
                                    <CheckBox.Content>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource sumConverter}">
                                            <Binding Path="Name"/>
                                            <Binding Path="Status"/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </CheckBox.Content>
                                </CheckBox>
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImagemStatus}" Width="16" Height="16"
     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,2,0,0" />
                                <Button x:Name="btnRemoveFromGroup"     Click="btnRemoveFromGroup_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="16px" Height="16px"
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" Foreground="{x:Null}"
 ToolTipService.ToolTip="Remove from group" Content="
    {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type
     TreeViewItem}, AncestorLevel=2}, Path=DataContext.ObtainGroup}">
                                    <Button.Background>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Imagens/Grp.png"/>
                                    </Button.Background>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TreeView>

<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Name="border" 
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            Padding="4,2" 
                            BorderBrush="DarkGray" 
                            CornerRadius="3" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Collapsing will not remove them from the instance (from the memory) you will have to dispose the instance of those nodes

Comment: So, the only way of getting rid of the space is either moving them to another list(for example) or deleting it?

Comment: Moving them will not remove them from the memory, you will have to dispose

Comment: Welp, guess I'll have to change some code then. Can you make an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ever you launch a process it takes some space in memory. When you create an instance it is also created in memory. And moving the data from one instance to another doesn't free the memory. You have to dispose the object to free it up.

Well ! in your case, you have `strings` in the `treeview` as nodes. A `treeviewNode` stores some extra information with it. If you don't want to `delete` the node, so you have another option.

You can save it in a `string` type `list` and can `dispose` that node from the `treeview`. A `list` doesn't store too much info as a `node` does. So it'll save some memory for you.

Comment: The garbage collector frees memory. Disposing is for cleaning up any resources that the class my contain that the GC can't deal with. There are numerous articles discussing how the GC and the Dispose pattern works. I suggest looking this up.

Answer (score 0):

You're attacking the problem wrong. You should setup a recursive function on your objects that uses CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView on each collection and set the Filter on each. This filter will then remove those items from the treeview, but not actually delete them. You can then, recursively, set the filter to null and all your items will be visible again.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem could be solved with the following code:

```
<TreeView x:Name="UserTree">
     <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
             <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsVisible}" />
         </Style>
      </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

      ...

</TreeView>
```

In your class "UserList" you have to declare a property called "IsVisible". When setting this property to "collapsed", the treeviewitem doesn't take any space in the treeview